# ExecuteReader : CommandText property has not been initialized when using gridView

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a gridView that I want to populate using the ExecuteReader function. When I run my program it gives the following error "ExecuteReader : CommandText property has not been initialized".

aspx.cs

```
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
    //creates a list of items to be displayed 
        var stockItems = new List<StockUpdate>();

    //creates the SQL command to retrieve the data from the table

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        command.CommandText = dsrFilteredBranches.InsertCommand;
        command.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();

    //populates the table
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                stockItems.Add(new StockUpdate
                {
                    BranchCode = rd["BranchCode"].ToString(),
                    StockTakeID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["StockTakeID"].ToString()),
                    Name = rd["Name"].ToString(),
                    Description = rd["Description"].ToString(),
                    StocktakeDate = rd["StocktakeDate"].ToString(),
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Quantity"].ToString())     
                });
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
        dgvStockTake.DataSource = stockItems;
        dgvStockTake.DataBind();

    }
```

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvStockTake" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style8" DataKeyNames="BranchCode">

        <%-- creates the editable columns for the gridView --%>        

        <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BranchCode">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBranchCode" Text='<%# Bind("BranchCode") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text='<%# Bind("StockTakeID") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descrption">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDescription" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StockTakeDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStocktakeDate" Text='<%# Bind("StocktakeDate") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="backColor" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'>
                </asp:Textbox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

class

```
public class StockUpdate
{
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    public int StockTakeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StocktakeDate { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using a SQLDataSource as the data source for my gridView but when I do that my entire gridView along with its HTML code disappeared. That is why I am using the DataReader.

When I replace "dsrFilteredBranches.InsertCommand" with my actual SQL command it gives me an error saying scalar variable @BranchCode has not been initialized and I also have not been able to solve that issue.

I have been struggling with this for hours now and any support would be appreciated.

Comment: What value you have in `dsrFilteredBranches.InsertCommand` ? What is you actual SQL command for insert?

Comment: My command is `SELECT [StockTakeID],Name, Description, StocktakeDate, Quantity FROM man.rptStocktakeActualtest WHERE (BranchCode = @BranchCode)
AND (DATEPART(YEAR,[StocktakeDate])=@Year)
AND (DATEPART(MONTH,[StocktakeDate])=@Month)
ORDER BY Name, StocktakeDate DESC`

Comment: You query has parameters in it. When you use this query you need to add parameters and theirs values in SQLCommand object. Read [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx?m=1) to learn about using parametrized queries in C#

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SqlCommand has parameters that you need to set before executing it. You can do it like this:

```
command.CommandText = dsrFilteredBranches.InsertCommand;

SqlParameter yourParameter = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@YourParameter",
    Value = YourParameterValue
};

command.Parameters.Add(yourParameter);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ! But now my gridView no longer shows up so I'll take a look at that.